# Is it possible to restore deleted packages from a private npm repository?

Tags: npm, package, backup

In my company we have a private npm repository where we host some of our projects, so that we can install them on our applications. Today, I was trying to create a new package but somehow, by accident, it seems that I have deleted all the packages within our organization. Is there any way to undo my action and restore those packages?

So far I've tried to look on the npm website for a history of actions or a way to undo my actions, but I couldn't find anything. I also sent an e-mail to the npm support team, to see if someone can help with this issue.

Ideally, I would expect that npm has some kind of back-up system that I could use to restore my deleted packages. If that's not possible, then I guess my only option would be to re-publish these packages, but this means I lose the version history of all of them...

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** a few hours after contacting npm support team they replied my e-mail saying everything was restored. Thanks npm team!